# MySQL not using index on DATE when used with '<' or '>' operators?

Tags: mysql

I'm using explain to test these queries. The col type is DATE

**this uses index:**

```
explain SELECT events.* FROM events WHERE events.date = '2010-06-11'
```

**this doesnt**

```
explain SELECT events.* FROM events WHERE events.date >= '2010-06-11'
```

index as follows (phpmyadmin)

```
Action  Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Field   Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
Edit    Drop    PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  event_id    18  A       
Edit    Drop    date    BTREE   No  No  date    0   A
```

i notice cardinality is 0, though there are some rows with the same date..

Comment: Cardinality 0 is a bit odd. Try running `ANALYZE TABLE events` and then try again?

Comment: and does the output of `EXPLAIN` still state that the index has cardinality 0?

Comment: If you actually run the query, does it give the output you would expect?

Comment: yep, still cardin of 0, yep, gets correct results

Comment: doesn't cardinality 0 => all values are the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If MySQL doesn't use the index, it has seen your query, and estimated that a table scan would probably be faster then using the index (in terms of IO / disk operations required probably). You can use a `FORCE INDEX`  and check whether this query will actually be faster using the index or not.

```
SELECT events.* FROM events
FORCE INDEX (date)
WHERE events.date >= '2010-06-11';
```

Comment: yes i think you're right, as its a test table with only 20rows (will be tens of thousands). how do i implement FORCE (to test)? this doesnt work: explain SELECT events.* FROM events WHERE events.date >= '2010-06-11' FORCE INDEX(date)