# Why optimizer use 'ALL' type instead of 'index' type?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm currently learning `execution plan` in `MySql`.
And I use dump data from here.

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/sakila-structure.html

I added new index to `from_date` field of `dept_emp` table, named `ix_fromdate`.
And I typed like below

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM dept_emp
WHERE from_date>='1985-01-01'
```

Execution plain result like below
[image]

I understand that `rows` value is closer amount of this table rows amount and optimizer didn't use `range` index.
And.. I think, `type` should be `index`, but `ALL`.
Why they did `table full scan`?
There's index for `ix_fromdate`, why they didn't use it though?
I know `index full scan` is better than `table full scan`...
Do I know it wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL not using index on DATE when used with '<' or '>' operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068989/mysql-not-using-index-on-date-when-used-with-or-operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Even if you have `INDEX(from_date)`?
- But more than about 20% of the table satisfies `WHERE from_date>='1985-01-01'`?

Then the Optimizer decides that it is probably faster to simply scan through the data, filtering as it goes.  The alternative (using the index) could be costly because of bouncing between the index BTree and the data BTree.

Use a newer date; the Optimizer may change its mind and use the index.